# Use of the word 'child'

Tags: word-usage

Let's suppose that Mr. X has a daughter and a son. The daughter is twenty-five. The son is twenty-three. For them, if we use the word ‘children’ in context with their parent(s), will it be fine? Or will it given an impression that they are less than thirteen or they are so young? Example:

> Mr. X has married his children off last year.

Does this sentence make sense? Or does it give an impression that Mr. X married his children off underage?

Comment: No, your children are your children no matter how old they are.

Answer (score 2):

The word "children" can refer to adult children.  However, there is a subtle mistake in your sentence.  It should use the simple past tense rather than the present perfect:

> Mr. X married his children off last year.

The reason is that the action is in the past, and the time at which it took place is specified.  If you didn't specify "last year", you would have to use the present perfect:

> Mr. X has married his children off.

For more details on when to use the present perfect, see: 
https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/present-perfect/

Answer (score 1):

One way to "workaround" is to use the synonym "offspring". It has the added benefit of not implying young age, but it sounds too impersonal.

A bigger confusion can be created by:

> Mr. X has married his children

especially to a foreign unexperienced speaker / listener, as it may (wrongly) be understood as "Mr. X got married to his children".

To workaround this misunderstanding, I would rephrase like this:

> Mr. X's children got married last year.

or

> The children of Mr. X got married last year.

Comment: "offspring" is usually a collective noun and rarely takes an 's'. See this https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/248813/what-is-the-correct-plural-form-of-offspring